# No Keyword with name 'Get Json Value' Found Error or any Keywords that I use in HttpLibrary.HTTP in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, robotframework, web-api-testing

I am using Robotframework-httplibrary for automating API calls which in this case I want to get the value of the token produced by POST method. So that I can use it on the PUT method to change the password. but unfortunately I've been enountering this error that keywords are not found even though I already declared the library.

This is a quick example

```
*** Settings ***
Library  HttpLibrary.HTTP
Library  Collections
Library  JSONLibrary
Library  SeleniumLibrary



*** Variables ***
${web_service}=  http://10.0.50.168:18000

*** Test Cases ***

Create Large JSON Document
    ${document}=  Catenate
    ...  {
    ...  "token" : "oPVo3b3NdkW8uDL2tiyZii"
    ...  }
    Should Be Valid JSON    ${document}
    ${result}=       Get Json Value  ${document}  token
    Should Be Equal  ${result}       "oPVo3b3NdkW8uDL2tiyZii"
```

Comment: Could you edit the question with the execution log which shows the error?

Comment: Are you certain you're notting getting an error on the import. There really are only two possible answers: there is an error when importing, or the library genuinely doesn't have a keyword with that name.

Answer (score 2):

You have set `python-3.x` as a question tag so I assume you're running Python 3.x on your machine. The `HttpLibrary` (`robotframework-httplibrary` package) is made for Python 2.x so it's not compliant with your version. There are numerous renamed functions and old syntax exception handling done within that library so there is no way for you to run it using Python 3.

You may either seek a different approach or downgrade your machine's Python & Robot Framework installations into Python 2.X compliant versions.

I see you want to call `Should Be Valid JSON` and `Get Json Value`. This can be achieved without the `HttpLibrary` as well:

You may employ the Python's `json` library's `json.loads()` to validate JSON. If it's not valid json, it will raise an exception.

Instead of `Get Json Value` you can just store the JSON into a dictionary and read the appropriate field.

Here is an example of validating JSON format, fetching `token` from the JSON and then asserting it is as expected:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Create Large JSON Document
    ${document}=  Catenate
    ...  {
    ...  "token" : "oPVo3b3NdkW8uDL2tiyZii"
    ...  }

    # Verify json is a valid format and set it to dictionary:
    &{JSON}=  Evaluate  json.loads('''${document}''')  json

    # Get token from JSON
    ${result}=  Set Variable  ${JSON['token']}
    Should Be Equal  ${result}       oPVo3b3NdkW8uDL2tiyZii
```